# move_uploaded_file not working anymore

Tags: php, file-upload

I made a website a couple of year ago which has worked fine till now.

now, when I try to load an image from the backend it raises me some warning and the Image fails to be moved in the destination directory.

here is the warning I get

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(path/image_name.jpg): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in
>   D:\inetpub\webs\remote_directory\php_script_name.php on line 184
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\PHPVersions\PHP55\uploadtemp\php418A.tmp' to 'path/image_name.jpg'
>   in D:\inetpub\webs\remote_directory\php_script_name.php on line 184

here is the line giving me the warning

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_'.$pos]['tmp_name'], 'path/'."part_of_image_name".$_FILES['img_'.$pos]['name'])) {
          $msg = "<p>Error loading image!!</p>";
          break;
        }
```

it does not even print the error message.

I tried to change permissions on directory (and all subdirs and files) via ftp but I'm not sure it succeded because it was giving me the following message

> Comando:  SITE CHMOD 740 Photo4.jpg.
>   Risposta:   500 'SITE': command not
>   understood

(by the way I read [somewhere](http://www.meetup.com/it/phpphp/messages/boards/thread/1950602) that it does not fix the problem. However the guy said he solved by using some magic which is not working for me - or I'm misunderstanding how to do it)

Everything worked until a few days/weeks ago (the customer wasn't clear on that point) so I just wanted to know if this is a kind of known issue or what (and a possible solution), since after a littlebit of research I could not find anything usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out to solve the problem by using the control panel of site hosting provider to change manually permissions on directory.

Answer (score 0):

try this, but first create a directory named uploads in the root directory:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: Could not figure out how this workaround would work. By the way I tried it but it didn't worked. Thanks anyway for Your try